# How to end game if bool value is true for winner? C++

Tags: c++, boolean

So, I am working on a tic-tac-toe program.  I have set up a boolean function and it works - it displays "Player 1 has Won!" When 3 X's are found in the given array numbers, but how can I force the program to stop?

I tried assigning `i = 9` so the `for` loop would stop running (and thus stop allowing the input of a number to place an `X` or `O`.  This is a very introductory-level program, so if you can help, please keep it as basic as possible.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tictactoe.h"

using namespace std;

char board[9] {
    '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'
};
bool winner;

void checkWinner(void) {
    bool tie;

    if (board[0] == 'X' && board[1] == 'X' && board[2] == 'X') {
        winner = 1;
        cout << "Player 1 Wins!" << endl;

    }
    else if (board[0] == 'Y' && board[1] == 'Y' && board[2] == 'Y'){
        winner = 1;
        cout << "Player 2 Wins!" << endl;
    }
}


void displayBoard(void) {

int index;
int movePosition;
    bool gameOver;

    index = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (winner == 1) {
            i += 9;
            cout << "Player 1 Wins!" << endl;
        }
    cout << "Player 1 is X, player 2 is O" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << board[index] << "|" << board[index+1] << "|" << board[index+2] << endl;
    cout << "-----" << endl;
    cout << board[index+3] << "|" << board[index+4] << "|" << board[index+5] << endl;
    cout << "-----" << endl;
    cout << board[index+6] << "|" << board[index+7] << "|" << board[index+8] << endl;

        cout << "Enter the space number where you would like to place X" << endl;
        checkWinner();
        if (winner == 1) {
            gameOver = true;
        }
        cin >> movePosition;

            while ((board[movePosition - 1] == 'X' || board[movePosition - 1] == 'O')) {
                cout << "This space is already taken.  Please choose an open space." << endl;
                cin >> movePosition;
            }

            board[movePosition - 1] = 'X';

            cout << "Enter the space number where you would like to place O" << endl;
            cin >> movePosition;

            while ((board[movePosition - 1] == 'X' || board[movePosition - 1] == 'O')) {
                cout << "This space is already taken.  Please choose an open space." << endl;
                cin >> movePosition;
            }

            board[movePosition - 1] = 'O';
    }
}



int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    displayBoard();


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `exit(0)` after checking if player 1 is the winner, to exit the program.

Or, change the function to  `bool checkWinner()` to be able to return a `bool`.

```
bool checkWinner(void) 
{
    bool winner = false;

    if (board[0] == 'X' && board[1] == 'X' && board[2] == 'X') {
        winner = true;
        cout << "Player 1 Wins!" << endl;

    }
    else if (board[0] == 'Y' && board[1] == 'Y' && board[2] == 'Y'){
        winner = true;
        cout << "Player 2 Wins!" << endl;
    }

    return winner;
}
```

In the `displayBoard()` function, you can then retrieve the return value, by

```
if ( checkWinner() )
{
    std::cout << "We have a winner" << std::end;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Which line?  I have one in the boolean `checkWinner` function, and also under my `displayBoard` function.  Either place I put it, it tells me that because the function is void it cannot return a value.  Should the boolean function not be void?

Comment: Just put `exit(0)` after every win condition. That will exit it. If you want to do it more cleanly, then return a `bool` and use that to exit the `displayBoard()` function. But using an `exit(0)` here is the most basic approach.

Comment: @AlanStokes I've taken your suggestion and expanded on it a bit.

Comment: Thank you guys very much..  I thought that it would be just as easy to check for a tie game - essentially, when every character place on the board is filled and no one has won, I want the program to terminate.

When I try and do this - either under the `checkWinner()` or in its own `tieGame` function (also tried a bool `tieGame`) - I don't know how to set up the statement.  Any suggestions?  I don't know how to search the array to see if all the spaces have been filled.